# Can I use “wicked sick” in this way

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Can I say that I am wicked sick in my job if I am too good at it. 
I heard that in dota2 “wicked sick” but in google did not find any meaning so I translate it that should be similar to ownage!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Wicked%20Sick) that can mean that you are virtuous because you are extremely good at something, particularly a video game. However, I would caution you to use the phrase only in the appropriate social context. It's slang and won't be readily understood by people who are not part of the gaming culture or in a certain age bracket. It's not a standard English expression.

To most people the words mean something like 'evil unhealthy', which doesn't make any sense at all. 'Wicked sick' can also describe something that has been badly damaged, which is closer to the literal meaning of the words.

Comment: "Wicked" has had a slang meaning of very good, impressive, exciting, etc, since at least 1990 in urban Britain.

Comment: It's used like that in the Northeast of the U.S. too.